# Setting a value in a function as a variable outside the function (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocation

I want to grab newRecordLat and newRecordLong and save them as a variable outside the function.  The purpose is because I want to store these variables in a database. They are currently outputting in CLLocationDegrees, not a string, int, float, or double.  I did read somewhere that CLLocationDegrees is a double...

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = addressTextField.text
    println(addressTextField.text)
    println("addressTextField.text^^")
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
        println(localSearchResponse)
        println("localSearchResponse^^")

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: nil, message: "Place not found", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
            alert.show()
            return
        }


        //GRAB newRecordLat and newRecordLong AND STORE THEM OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION

        var newRecordLat = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude
        var newRecordLong = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your `newRecordLat` and `newRecordLong` variables as properties of your class. To do this, move both declarations out side of `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`.

```
class MyClass: UITextFieldDelegate {

    var newRecordLat: CLLocationDegrees?
    var newRecordLong: CLLocationDegrees?

    ...
    ...


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = addressTextField.text
        println(addressTextField.text)
        println("addressTextField.text^^")
        localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
        println(localSearchResponse)
        println("localSearchResponse^^")
            if localSearchResponse == nil {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: nil, message: "Place not found", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
            alert.show()
            return
        }

        self.newRecordLat = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude
        self.newRecordLong = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude
}
```